# Translating these "payoff matrices" to normal form.

Tags: matrices, game-theory

I'm used to looking at payoffs to given players in normal form but here I'm given the following matrices and asked to interpret them as payoff matrices. Can someone explain how I'd translate the given matrices into normal form so I can understand what I'm, looking at?

\begin{pmatrix}1 & 2\\
3 & 4
\end{pmatrix}

\begin{pmatrix}2 & 4 & 6 & 3\\
6 & 2 & 4 & 3\\
4 & 6 & 2 & 3
\end{pmatrix}

Also, I'm new to LaTeX and am having trouble with formatting; I'd like to have "A=" and "B=" immediately next to each matrix respectively but I end up with them being left justified while the corresponding matrix is centered, how can I fix this?

Comment: Are these zero-sum games?

Comment: Yes, I believe they are.